# Trouble copying a CSV into an array in java

Tags: java, csv

So this is my first time trying to do something like this, and I've been gathering information from various sources online on how to properly do this. So far, I have written a code to which I believe will be able to get the job done. However, whenever I click run, the program terminates and prints this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Version,1.4.0"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at IO_CSV.setUpMyCSVArray(IO_CSV.java:47)
    at IO_CSV.main(IO_CSV.java:82)
```

This is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;


public class IO_CSV {

    static String xStrPath;
    static double[][] myArray;
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();

    static void setUpMyCSVArray()
    {
        myArray = new double[3000][3000];

        Scanner scanIn = null;
        int RowC= 0;
        int Row = 0;
        int ColC = 0;
        int Col = 0;
        String InputLine = " ";
        String xfileLocation;


        xfileLocation = "/Users/victorgarcia/Documents/reza_data1.csv"; 



        try
        {
            //setup scanner
            scanIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(xfileLocation)));

            //while ((InputLine = scanIn.nextLine()) != null)
            while(scanIn.hasNextLine())
            {
                //read line in from file
                InputLine = scanIn.nextLine();
                //split the InputLine into an array at the commas
                String[] InArray = InputLine.split(",,,");

                //copy the content of the inArray to the myArray
                for(int x = 0; x< InArray.length; x++)
                {
                    myArray[RowC][x] = Double.parseDouble(InArray[x]);
                }
                //increment the row in the array
                RowC++;
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        { 
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }





static void printMyArray()
{
    for (int RowC=0; RowC<3000; RowC++)
    {
        for (int ColC=0; ColC<3000; ColC++)
        {
            System.out.print(myArray[RowC][ColC]+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    return;
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    setUpMyCSVArray();


}
}
```

Hopefully somebody has an answer for me as to what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Could you give us a sample input file ? You are mistaking on the way to parse it so it would be nice to have an example to guide you

Comment: Also to note: your printMyArray() method can be improved. Instead of hard coding the values you can simply do:  static void printArray(double[][] toPrint){ for(int x = 0; x < toPrint.length; x++) { for(int y = 0; y < toPrint[x].length; y++) { System.out.print(toPrint[x][y]+" "); } System.out.println(); } return; }

Answer (score 1):

In this code you assume that all the values in the CSV can be parsed as double. This is not the case for the string "Version,1.4.0", which apparantly appears in your file. To catch this problem and log all other situations where the value cannot be parsed as a double, you can change your code like this:

```
try
{
    myArray[RowC][x] = Double.parseDouble(InArray[x]);
}
catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
{
    System.out.println("Unable to parse at " + rowC + ", " + x + ": " + InArray[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While it's relatively easy to come up with a simple self-made CSV parser, it is actually more complex problem than it seems from the surface. In the end, you may end up spending a fair amount of time polishing out problems like the ones you are having here, so it's not usually not worth it to implement your own one. There's plenty of open source implementation available (such as [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/)).